# RDP log files location in Windows 7 or 8

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, logging

I used RDP a few times on my Windows 7 PC, before upgrading to Windows 8. I was wondering if there are any log files associated with RDP sessions in Windows 7 and if so, what is the physical location of these files? I need to collect some information on previous sessions such as duration and start/end dates/times.

Since i don't have Windows 7 anymore, is there a chance these files may be in the Windows.old folder? Otherwise, What would be the physical location of RDP log files in a Windows 8 system?

Answer (score 1):

I think your question may be answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/409099/is-there-a-log-file-for-rdp-connections).
If you kept Windows.old folder as it looks like, you'll be able to quickly find the info you need.

Check the folder:

```
C:\Windows.old\System32\winevt\Logs
```

And load one of the files:

```
Microsoft-Windows-RemoteApp and Desktop Connections%4Admin.evtx
Microsoft-windows-RemoteDesktopServices-RemoteDesktopSessionManager%4Admin.evtx
Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager%4Admin.evtx
Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager%4Operational.evtx
```

Different info is in those files, but I'm sure you'll easily find what you need.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would expect Microsoft applications to write any log records to the "Application" section of the Windows event log normally held in C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\