# Log user back in after Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, remote

I'm sitting with an issue where I am doing a remote desktop connection to a POS system which works fine. When I remote in the existing user gets logged out of their computer as expected with remote desktop connection.

Now when i'm done with the remote connection the user stays logged out. I want the user to be automatically be logged back in again after I disconnect.

Reason being they ask for ctrl alt delete password to be provided, however the POS machine doesn't have any keyboard connected. Both machines run Windows 10.

Anyone have an idea if this is even possible or if there is some kind of workaround.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: … or disable the ctrl/alt/delete requirement… Run `netplwiz` advanced tab, uncheck ctrl-alt-delete, supply admin password if requested. Done.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restore console session after remote desktop disconnects?](https://superuser.com/questions/767397/restore-console-session-after-remote-desktop-disconnects)