# Is there a log file of RDP outgoing connections?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

Is there windows log (file, registry, event log) where can I find information about outgoing RDP connection?

I'm looking for information like:

- destination host (ip/hostname)
- connection time
- session duration
- was connection successful?
- how it was closed?

**Important**: This is reverse of [Is there a log file for RDP connections?](https://superuser.com/questions/409099/is-there-a-log-file-for-rdp-connections) which is about **incoming** connection.

Example:

```
10:00 failed login to server X (authorization error)
10:01 successful login to server X (01:12:00)
12:31 successful login to server Y (00:05:41)
15:11 successful login to workstation iii.iii.ii.ii (00:10:10)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a log file for RDP connections?](https://superuser.com/questions/409099/is-there-a-log-file-for-rdp-connections)

Comment: @Moab: The other is for incoming connections, while the poster asks about outgoing ones.

Comment: If there is a log generated by windows it would have in and out connections. The question titles are an exact match. Is there an RDP log file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The outgoing connections are stored in "Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RDPClient%4Operational.evtx"

The incoming connections are stored in different log files, as the OP suggests.

Comment: Nice. Based on your answer I found that there is also `Microsoft > Windows> TerminalServices-ClientActiveXCore > Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RDPClient/Operational`. But 1. I don't remember what for I need it 2. Can't test it from home-office

Comment: Here about same problem: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f6a9cc70-6cf1-4c8e-853b-d023e1bd4842/solved-remote-desktop-connection-and-windows-event-logs?forum=win10itpronetworking, and some more info https://jpcertcc.github.io/ToolAnalysisResultSheet/details/mstsc.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the windows event logs:security EventID 4648, which records Logins using explicit credentials. If someone logs in to a remote computer from a host using rdp, it will generate EventId 4648 where the TargetComputerName is the remote host.